# How to convert number (int or float64) to string in Golang

Tags: string, go, casting, integer

How do I convert any given number which can be a int or float64 to string ?

Using strconv.FormatFloat or FormatInt I have to specify that the given number is a float or integer.
In my case it is unknown what I get.

Behaviour:

When I get a `5` it should be converted into `"5"` and not `"5.00"`

When I get a `1.23` it should be converted into `"1.23"` and not `"1"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use `fmt.Sprint`

`fmt.Sprint` returns string format of any variable passed to it

**Sample**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    f := fmt.Sprint(5.03)
    i := fmt.Sprint(5)
    fmt.Println("float:",f,"\nint:",i)
}
```

[play link](https://play.golang.org/p/8ZgjjO2k3X)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what type the number you need to convert to string will be, you can just use `fmt.Sprintf` with the `%v` verb:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%v", 1.23) // "1.23"
fmt.Sprintf("%v", 5) // "5"
```